# ImapMailReceiver stopped with taskScheduler thread supplied being blocked

Tags: java, spring, email, imap

ImapMailReceiver stopped with taskScheduler thread supplied being blocked. We are not able to receive messages due to receiver thread is blocked. How to monitor or health checkup if ImapMailReceiver is running. Any class to extend from Spring to monitor if ImapMailReceiver is running?

Configuration as below

```
@Configuration("ImapAutoReply")
@EnableIntegration
@ComponentScan("com.mailbox.*")
public class ImapConfiguration {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ImapConfiguration.class);

    @Autowired
    private ImapUtil imapUtil;

    @Autowired
    private ThreadPoolTaskScheduler taskScheduler;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        LOGGER.debug("Imap Configuration initialized..");
    }

    @Bean
    ImapIdleChannelAdapter mailAdapter() {
        ImapIdleChannelAdapter imapIdleChannelAdapter = new ImapIdleChannelAdapter(mailReceiver());
        imapIdleChannelAdapter.setAutoStartup(true);
        imapIdleChannelAdapter.setOutputChannel(directChannel());
        imapIdleChannelAdapter.setTaskScheduler(taskScheduler);
        imapIdleChannelAdapter.start();
        return imapIdleChannelAdapter;
    }

    @Bean
    ImapIdleChannelAdapter spamMailAdapter() {
        ImapIdleChannelAdapter imapIdleChannelAdapter = new ImapIdleChannelAdapter(spamMailReceiver());
        imapIdleChannelAdapter.setAutoStartup(true);
        imapIdleChannelAdapter.setOutputChannel(directChannel());
        imapIdleChannelAdapter.setTaskScheduler(taskScheduler);
        imapIdleChannelAdapter.start();
        return imapIdleChannelAdapter;
    }
    
    @Bean
    ImapMailReceiver mailReceiver() {
        ImapMailReceiver mailReceiver = new ImapMailReceiver(imapUtil.getImapMailReceiverURL());
        mailReceiver.setJavaMailProperties(javaMailProperties());
        mailReceiver.setShouldDeleteMessages(false);
        mailReceiver.setShouldMarkMessagesAsRead(true);
        mailReceiver.setJavaMailAuthenticator(javaMailAuthenticator());
        return mailReceiver;
    }

    @Bean
    ImapMailReceiver spamMailReceiver() {
        ImapMailReceiver mailReceiver = new ImapMailReceiver(imapUtil.getImapSpamMailReceiverURL());
        mailReceiver.setJavaMailProperties(javaMailProperties());
        mailReceiver.setShouldDeleteMessages(false);
        mailReceiver.setShouldMarkMessagesAsRead(true);
        mailReceiver.setJavaMailAuthenticator(javaMailAuthenticator());
        return mailReceiver;
    }
    
    @Bean
    public DirectChannel directChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    private Properties javaMailProperties() {
        Properties javaMailProperties = new Properties();

        javaMailProperties.setProperty("mail.imap.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        javaMailProperties.setProperty("mail.imap.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
        javaMailProperties.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");
        javaMailProperties.setProperty("mail.debug", "true");

        return javaMailProperties;
    }

    @Bean
    public Authenticator javaMailAuthenticator() {
        return new Authenticator() {
            @Override
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(imapUtil.getInboundUser(), imapUtil.getInboundPassword());
            }
        };
    }

}
```

Error of thread dump during block

```
javax.mail.Folder.removeMessageCountListener(Folder.java:1525)
org.springframework.integration.mail.ImapMailReceiver.waitForNewMessages(ImapMailReceiver.java:178)
org.springframework.integration.mail.ImapIdleChannelAdapter$IdleTask.run(ImapIdleChannelAdapter.java:220)
org.springframework.integration.mail.ImapIdleChannelAdapter$ReceivingTask.run(ImapIdleChannelAdapter.java:190)
org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81)
java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Check whether some NAT middlebox is discarding your connections silently, and get better network equipment if so.

Comment: If the connection would have been choked / discarded, then we will get FolderClosedException. Issue is that the thread is being blocked, we are able to see that in profiler. What ever issue could be, I want to monitor imapreciver connection so we can take proper action, looking for a solution if any class we can extend so that we can monitor such

Comment: You may not get that exception. Lots of bad NAT boxes allow you to make the connection, open the mailbox and then start dropping your packets silently (without an error message) after a minute or so.